# How can I display the right dateformat with angular bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap datepicker for angular but having issues with displaying the correct dateformat. The format I am getting now is:
"2015-09-08T00:56:40.272Z". The format I want is dd-mmm-yyyy.

This is my datepicker:

```
<p class="input-group">

  selected date:{{dt}}

    <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt"
           is-open="opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions"
           date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" my-date/>

              <span class="input-group-btn">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>

              </span>
</p>
```

I tried this:
[Angular bootstrap datepicker date format does not format ng-model value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24198669/angular-bootsrap-datepicker-date-format-does-not-format-ng-model-value).

But did not fix the issue. How can I get the right dateformat?

plunkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/CbNHCl?p=preview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24198669/angular-bootsrap-datepicker-date-format-does-not-format-ng-model-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean where you have `selected date:{{dt}}`? You simply need to format it there using the `date` filter

```
selected date:{{dt | date:format}}
```

This is because your `dt` model will be a `Date` instance.

http://plnkr.co/edit/zKWXwb?p=preview

Comment: ok when I want to set it in js? something like = $filter('date')($scope.dt, $scope.format) ?