# AngularJS Bootstrap dateTime- picker date format dd.MM.yyyy

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I use this dateTime- Picker and I have the problem that I can not set a date with formate dd.MM.yyyy into my model **iuc.scheduleAbsenceHeader.activationDate**. If I am doing this, I get the error:

> Datepicker directive: "ng-model" value must be a Date object, a number of milliseconds since 01.01.1970 or a string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date.

Has anyone any idea how I can solve this?

```
<input type="text"
       class="form-control"
       name="systemEntryDate"                                
       ng-model="iuc.scheduleAbsenceHeader.activationDate"
       ng-change="vm.updateScheduleAbsenceHeader(iuc)"
       datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy"
       is-open="iuc.scheduleAbsenceHeader.openedDatePicker"
       close-text="schlie&szlig;en"
       current-text="heute"
       clear-text="l&ouml;schen">
<span class="input-group-btn">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"                                 
         ng-click="vm.openDatePickerSystemEntry($event, institutionUserConnection)"><span
         class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) I can successfully set a dateTime picker's value to the current dateTime like so:

```
vm.myDate = moment((moment().toISOString())).format("MM.DD.YYYY")
```

Otherwise, have a [look at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24198669/angular-bootsrap-datepicker-date-format-does-not-format-ng-model-value).